# Automatically replace strings in different language

Tags: craft3, localization, multi-site

We have sites for Germany and Switzerland that are pretty much identical but would like to cater to the spelling differences in Switzerland (namely replacing "ß" with "ss"). Is there any way to run the whole content of the German sites through a filter replacing characters where needed for the Swiss site? Since most content identical it would save us from having to update the same content twice. The Twig replace filter could do that but then I would have to set the filter for each field if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Nothing I can think of without doing some custom PHP/SQL code... is that something you're comfortable with?

Comment: Unfortunately not to that extent. Will have to think of something else then but thanks anyway!